# How to connect PayPal to a rails app using active merchant? Any tutorials?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal, activemerchant

Are there any good tutorials on how to connect paypal to activemerchant? Rails cast episode is very old and I need something for Rails 4. And another problem, in rails cast, they initiate the gateway in the initializer. But in the activemerchant documentation they initiate it in right before the payment. I think it's in the controller. What is the right and secure way to do it?

PS : I need people to go to PAYPAL and make the payments either by giving credit card or through paypal account.

Comment: you mean that, do you need to integrate paypal into your application

Answer (score 3):

One of the ways to do it is to write a module or a class that wraps the following steps. Make sure you're passing the right values and the totals are adding up.

**1. Prepare Gateway**

```
    paypal_express_params = {
      login: ENV['PAYPAL_LOGIN'],
      password: ENV['PAYPAL_PASSWORD'],
      signature: ENV['PAYPAL_SIGNATURE']
    }

    gateway = ActiveMerchant::Billing::PaypalExpressGateway.new(paypal_express_params)
```

**2. Setup Purchase**

```
    setup_hash = {
        ip: '170.170.1.1', 
        items: [{name: 'sample', quantity: 1, amount: 100_00, description: 'desc'}], 
        subtotal: 10000, 
        shipping: 0, 
        handling: 0, 
        tax: 0, 
        currency: 'USD', 
        return_url: 'http://localhost:3000/success', 
        cancel_return_url: 'http://localhost:3000/failure', 
        allow_guest_checkout: true
    }
    response = gateway.setup_purchase(100_00, setup_hash) # 100 USD
```

**3. Generate PayPal URL**

```
    url = gateway.redirect_url_for(response.token)
    # => https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

After that, you just have to catch the data from PayPal after the user has completed purchase.

There are several ways to do this but the important thing is to:

> 1. Make it work first
> 2. Ensure that the keys and secrets are not hardcoded in your Rails code
> 3. Wrap the code in a class or module to clean things up
> 4. Read the PayPal documentation as well (not just ActiveMerchant)

Comment: Is there a way to encrypt the url like in here http://railscasts.com/episodes/143-paypal-security ?

Comment: I believe they are encrypting the values in the page to prevent users from updating the hidden field values directly. We're redirecting the users to the PayPal page we've prepared beforehand so there's no need to use encryption (since we're not placing payment values in hidden fields accessible by the customers).

Comment: I have a small problem. This code does not make the purchase... I can't see money getting transferred!